# How to run magento 2 command php bin/magento regenerate:product:url programmatically

Tags: magento2

Anyone have idea how to run below magento 2 command programmatically

php bin/magento regenerate:product:url

Thanks

Comment: system('php bin/magento regenerate:product:url')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP exec() function